# How can I recreate this masking effect in CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, mask, grayscale

I'm trying to recreate the effect shown in the gif here. It's fine even to have two separate images - I don't need to recreate the greyscale/blur effect (although I can with webkit filters) - it's just the masking that I'm having trouble with.

Basically I've got a carousel slider, and as it slides left and right, the background underneath the current slide will be blurred, to make the text on top more visible. I can't manage to keep the background in the same place as the slider moves along as a mask. How can I recreate this?

[image]

edit: I've managed to figure this out: http://jsfiddle.net/9xk410wk/18/
I used CSS transforms in opposite directions:

```
.tile {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-400px, 0px, 0px);
}
.blur > div {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(400px, 0px, 0px);
}
.tile:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(400px, 0px, 0px);
}
.tile:hover .blur > div {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-400px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far (your code, your issues) ? Because a question like "I need you to do that" is not a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @singe31 sorry, I didn't have a chance to put up my work so far. I have managed to solve it- solution in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a webkit grayscale filter for this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/36Tpt/9/)** (hover over the image to see the effect)

### Markup

```
<div class="pic">
    <div class="mask">SLIDER</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.pic {
    width:288px;
    height: 214px;
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51558405/pic.png) no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.pic:hover  .mask {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(228px, 0, 0);
    background-position: 100% 0;
}
.mask {
    width: 60px;
    height: 214px;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51558405/pic.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s linear;
    transition: all 1.5s linear;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: The `%` background doesn't align correctly. Pretty smart though!

Comment: It's almost right with `left: 228px;`, but you still see the shake of 2 different background elements...

Comment: Thanks @Rudie - I just updated the fiddle with that fix

Comment: It's a bit wobbly - I achieved a similar solution with CSS transforms that are a little smoother.

Comment: @morgoe - I edited the transitions with transforms - It's a bit hard to tell, but I think it is a little smoother

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly the issue you are running into without seeing code, but here is a crude fiddle that I created which mimics the gif:

http://jsfiddle.net/z71g26by/

I just used a CSS3 linear animation and changed the opacity of the moving panel. I just used colors, but it should work the same with a background image.

CSS:

```
body {
    /*To hide the horizontal scroller */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    width: 500px; 
    height: 420px; 
    background-color:blue;
}

.panel { 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 420px; 
    background-color: white; 
    opacity: .8; 
    -webkit-animation: move 5s linear infinite;

}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel"><p>SLIDER</p></div>
</div>
```

Note: This only works in webkit, but you can add the appropriate pre-fixes to get it working in other browsers.

Comment: Add some `overflow:hidden` because the horizontal scrolling bar appears

Comment: Oh noes! It's going the wrong way! Unacceptable and unusable!